# Can I Include an android library that uses an older gradle plugin in a newer project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a newer android project that's using the 2.3 gradle plugin in Android Studio.  I am trying to include an older android library that uses the 2.0.+ gradle plugin.

If I just compile the library by itself, it compiles successfully.  When I `include ':library'` and put this library in the main project's `dependencies{ compile project(':library') }`, I get the following error on Gradle Sync:

```
Error:(50, 0) Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

The library's `build.gradle` file has an `assembleDebug` block, and from this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732#c21, it seems to be related to some change in the 2.2 gradle plugin.

I'm not the author of the library, so I don't to change anything in the library itself, just use it.  Is it possible to include this older library in the newer project without having to modify the library's `build.gradle` file to work with the newer gradle version?

Comment: Is the library available as an artifact (e.g., in Maven Central, JCenter, or another public Maven-style repo), so you could skip trying to use it from source?

Comment: unfortunately no, it's checked out from an old internal svn repo.

Comment: Then, if it is your organization's own version control system... why do you not want to modify `build.gradle`? It's not like the old one will work going forward, apparently.

Comment: Because it's part of a much larger project (that is also old and it all still compiles and runs fine together).  I don't want to do anything that might impact the other project.